# Как сделать autosave

Tags: python

У меня есть скрипт

```
import random

name = f'T{random.randint(1, 9)}kEn'
famil = f'L{random.randint(1, 9)}{random.randint(1, 9)}kEnGG{random.randint(1, 9)}D'
mail = f'CrushALT-{random.randint(1,999999999999999)}'
pols = f'CrushALT-{random.randint(10,99)}'

with open('accounts.txt', 'w') as ac:
    ac.write(f'Account: {pols}'
             f'\nMail: {mail}'
             f'\n\n\n')
```

он записывает переменные туда, но при повторном запуске он перезаписывает это, а мне нужно чтобы он при повторном запуске он не перезаписывал, а добавлял ниже

Comment: А где же скрипт?

Comment: в плане @AlexeyTen

Comment: Приведённый код не может ничего перезаписать в accounts.txt потому что вообще ничего никуда не пишет.

Comment: @AlexeyTen я показал переменные которые нужно записать

Comment: Так проблема у вас не с переменными, а записью. Но почему-то этот код вы считаете очень большим секретом и не хотите показать

Comment: @AlexeyTen чек, обновил вопрос

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/fajly-rabota-s-fajlami.html читать про режимы открытия файла

Comment: @AlexeyTen thxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('accounts.txt', 'a') as ac:
    ac.write(f'Account: {pols}',
             f'\nMail: {mail}',
             f'\n\n\n')
```

Этот код при каждой записи будет не перезаписывать, а добавлять ниже.